# Why gtk css widget styling does not work?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala

I'm trying to style widget from inside of it's constructor in Vala but I don't get the result I want. Here is the original code sample:

```
public class MyWidget : Gtk.FlowBox {

    public MyWidget () {
        var css_provider = new Gtk.CssProvider ();
        try {
            css_provider.load_from_data (
                """
                label {
                    color: blue;
                }
                """
            );
            get_style_context ().add_provider (css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
        } catch (Error e) {
            message ("error");
        }
    }

    public void add_entry (string s) {
        var entry = new Gtk.Label (s);
        add (entry);
    }

}
```

I've tried all different variants of styling "flowbox", "flowboxchild", "label" etc. and only one that works is "*" for every element inside GtkFlowbox or assigning it to a class, thought I still can't style it's children. Priorities don't seem to change anything, adding global "flowbox" styles for screen context don't work too.

I've tried to do it using gtk inspector but no result here too.

So how do I style all children of widget? Or do I need to specify class for them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
public class MyWidget : Gtk.FlowBox {

    public MyWidget () {
        this.add_entry ("default text");
    }

    public void add_entry (string s) {
        var entry = new Gtk.Label (s);
        add (entry);
    }

}

void main (string[] args) {
    Gtk.init (ref args);

    var window = new Gtk.Window ();
    window.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);
    window.window_position = Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER;
    window.set_default_size (300, 80);
    window.add (new MyWidget ());

    var css_provider = new Gtk.CssProvider ();
    try {
        css_provider.load_from_data (
            """
            GtkLabel {
                color: blue;
            }
            """
        );
        Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen (
                                 Gdk.Screen.get_default (),
                                 css_provider,
                                 Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION
                                 );
    } catch (Error e) {
        message ("error loading CSS provider");
    }

    window.show_all ();

    Gtk.main ();
}
```

Compile with:

`valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 css_provider_example.vala`

[`add_provider`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#gtk-style-context-add-provider) is a provider for that widget only. `add_provider_for_screen` adds the stylesheet for all widgets in the application. I can understand `for_screen` can be a little misleading by making someone think it applies to all applications on that screen, but from what I can tell that is not the case.

I've moved the `add_provider_for_screen` section to the `main ()` block to clarify it is for the whole application. If you want the style to only apply to `GtkLabel`s inside `GtkFlowBox`es then the selector `GtkFlowBox GtkLabel` should work.

Also the terminology 'node' and 'selector' seems a little confusing. I had to change `label` in the GTK+ CSS to `GtkLabel`. A 'node' is probably the part of the widget that can be affected by the CSS rather than an identifier for selection, but anyone clarifying that would be very helpful! I have found that `.label` does work. So `label` is treated like a class name in CSS and `GtkLabel` like an element. Note the dot before `label`. `.flowbox` doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: So gtk documentation (both valadoc and gnome website) is a bit misleading saying that css nodes are named "flowbox", "label" etc. It's so confusing. Thanks for the answer, it finally works.

Comment: It looks like things changed a little with GTK+ 3.20. I've just found [A GTK+ update](https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2015/11/20/a-gtk-update/) blog post and [GTK+ Style Classes and Element Names](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK%2B/StyleClasses) wiki page